# Joint probability function, calculate $\mathbb{E}[X^2*Y]$

Tags: probability

Given the joint probability function:

[image]

I need to calculate $$\mathbb{E}[X^2*Y]$$

However, we dont know yet the Covariance formula so please dont use that.
Thank you!

Comment: What did you try? Hint: Which values can be attained by $X^2Y$? With which probability then?

Comment: Hint: write the values of $X^2Y$ in each entry of the table. For instance, the one in the top left will be $4$ since $2^2 \cdot 1=4$.

Comment: $E[X^2 Y] = \sum_{x} \sum_y x^2 y p(x,y)$. You know $p(x,y)$ as its given in the table, and $x$ takes on the values $2,4$ and $y$ takes on the values $1,3,5$.

Comment: @kccu Thank you. What with the top right 4 will be 16? And how to calculate the probability in the table now?

Comment: @LifeOfPai The probabilities are already in the table. Now you know the values $X^2Y$ takes on, so you can compute $E[X^2Y]$ by summing up (value of $X^2Y$) x (probability $X^2Y$ takes on that value) over all entries in the table.

Comment: @kccu How the probabilities same in table of Y\X and table of Y\X^2?

Comment: I've added an answer because the comments are too small to provide a full justification of the formula in @Batman's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition

> $$\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]=\sum_{z}z \cdot \mathbb{P}(X^2Y=z)$$

where the sum is over, say, all natural numbers $z$ (since $X^2Y$ only takes on positive integer values). I claim this is equal to

> $$\sum_{x}\sum_{y}x^2y \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=x \text{ and }Y=y)$$

(this is also what @Batman wrote in the comments). Let's see why.

> \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}[X^2Y]&=\sum_{z} z \cdot \mathbb{P}(X^2Y=z)\\
> &=\sum_z z \cdot \sum_x \sum_y \mathbb{P}(X^2Y=z \text{ and }X=x \text{ and }Y=y) \quad\quad \text{ (law of total probability)}\\
> &=\sum_x\sum_y\sum_z z \cdot \mathbb{P}(X^2Y=z \text{ and }X=x \text{ and }Y=y).
> \end{align*}

Now $\mathbb{P}(X^2Y=z \text{ and } X=x \text{ and }Y=y)$ is zero unless $z=x^2y$, so the sum over $z$'s only contains one non-zero term, which is $(x^2y)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X^2Y=x^2y \text{ and }X=x \text{ and }Y=y)$. So we have

> \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}[X^2Y]&=\sum_x \sum_y (x^2y)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X^2Y=x^2y \text{ and } X=x \text{ and }Y=y)\\
> &=\sum_x \sum_y (x^2y)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X=x \text{ and }Y=y).
> \end{align*}